# In Angular 2, my queryParams subscription gets called two times?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, subscription, url-parameters, query-string

Is this normal behavior? Does it get called on startup and when queryParams are loaded?

I subscribe to my queryParams in my ngOnInit() like this:

```
this.subscription = this.editorService.paramObs.subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
        /* my code here gets executed two times */
    }
)
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are using this particular component only once?

Comment: Yeah i'm pretty sure. See comment on Prosenjit Manna answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe on component destroy. Check more details: http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: `ngOnDestroy() {
        this.mouseChanged.unsubscribe();
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        console.log('DESTROYED COMPONENT');
    }`


This doesn't get logged on startup so i'm pretty sure i only use the component once.

Comment: Implement proper way ngOnDestroy. Can you show me component code.